# Reverse for 'edit' with arguments '(9,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm getting an error when trying to access edit link in django, i have looked here on stack overflow but i haven't found the solution that works in my case.

ERROR : 
Exception Type : NoReverseMatch 
Exception Value : Reverse for 'edit' with arguments '(9,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: [] arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

this is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from posts import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^create/$', views.create, name='create'),
    url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.show_post, name = 'show_post'),
    url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/edit/$', views.update_post, name = 'update_post'),
    url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/delete/$', views.delete_post),
]
```

views.py

```py
from django.contrib import messages
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect

from .forms import PostForm
from .models import Post

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    post_list = Post.objects.order_by('-created_date')[:10]
    context = {'post_list': post_list}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)

def create(request):
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        #flass messages
        messages.success(request, "Successfully created")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())


    context = {
        "form":form,
    }
    return render(request, 'post_form.html', context)   


def show_post(request, id=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    context = {'instance': instance}
    return render(request, 'show_post.html', context)


def update_post(request, id=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        messages.success(request, "Post updated")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
    context = {
        "form":form,
        "instance":instance
    }
    return render(request, 'post_form.html', context)


def delete_post(request, id=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    instance.delete()
    messages.success(request, "Successfully deleted")
    return redirect("posts:index")
```

show_post.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

<div class="container">
{% block content  %}
    <h1> {{instance.title}} </h1>
    <h3>{{instance.content| linebreaks}} </h3>
    <a href="{% url 'posts:index' %}"> Home</a> | <a href="{{instance.url}}" target="_blank" > visit url</a> | 
    <a href="{% url 'posts:update_post' %}"> Edit</a> 

{% endblock %}

</div>
```

Comment: Your `urls.py` doesn't have a url with `name='edit'`.

Comment: i changed the url name from name='update_post' to name='edit' but still i get an error.

Comment: @wemode you need to do the opposite, change `edit` to `update_post` in _show_post.html_

Comment: @vishes_shell as long as `urls.py` and `show_post.html` agree on the url name, why should it matter if he uses `edit` or `update_post`?

Comment: @vishes_shell i did that but no luck.

Comment: @JohnGordon it shouldn't matter, you're right, but i believe that aithor needs to change it to one name and update the question

Comment: The `update_post()` view expects an `id` keyword argument, which the `{% url %}` tag is not supplying.

Comment: @JohnGordon how do i supply that id?

Comment: `{% url 'posts:update_post' id=foo %}` obviously you will replace `foo` with `instance.id` or however you are storing the id value.

Comment: @JohnGordon Thanks it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the namespace. Rather than `'edit'`, you should use `'posts:edit'`.

Or `'posts:update_post'` depending which name you're using in urls.py.